# Не работает Series drop в python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Я сейчас учу Pandas c видео на YouTube и переписываю код тем самым обучаясь, когда дело дошло до удаления методом drop (Series) я столкнулся с багом. Cуть проблемы такова что с помощью drop я не могу удалить нужные элементы указав их labels, при выводе после удаления они выводятся как обычно если б их и не удаляли, даже полазив в интернете я не смог найти мне нужный ответ. Весь код представлен ниже.

Я был уже на этом сайте, но там показывают как в видео: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop.html

```
# Рандомное заполнение
s4 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(6), index=['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y'])
print(s4, '\n')

# Добавление и удаление
# добавление
s4['pylounge'] = 1000
print(s4, '\n')

# удаление, Удаление почему то не работает
print('Выяснить в чем причина неудаления: q, pylounge')
s4.drop(labels=['q', 'pylounge']) # labels, index, axis и т. д.
print(s4, '\n')
```

Comment: `s4 = s4.drop(....`

Comment: спасибо, чел и ютуба пользовался не редактором кода

Comment: Сейчас в `Pandas` местами ещё остался параметр `inplace` который можно выставить в `True` и менять какие-то сущности без присваивания, просто "по месту", но он будет выпилен в будущих версиях, так что имейте в виду - в любом случае все изменения нужно куда-то присваивать.

Answer (score 0):

s4 = s4.drop(labels=['q', 'pylounge'])

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]